# Trouble with running pip install

Tags: python, pip

> pip --version
>   ./node_modules/.bin/pip: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
>   ./node_modules/.bin/pip: line 1:`var freckle = require('freckle')

I have already reinstalled Python and whenever I try and use the pip command this comes up. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: This is not python's pip. A `nodejs` module exposes an executable with the same name. You may want to use `python -m pip install` to install python packages.

Comment: Please add this as an answer since it solves the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do `sudo pip install`. You might have other installed tools that are imposing on the install, such as homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

> This is not python's pip. A nodejs module exposes an executable with
>   the same name. You may want to use `python -m pip install` to install
>   python packages.

Provided by @cel

Answer (score 0):

You use Python version 2.7 or older you need to install python 3 with pip3 try it:
For Linux:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt install python3-pip`
3. `pip3 --version`

And now you can install your package for example:

```
pip3 install virtualenv
```