# Problems installing cryptography

Tags: python, cryptography, installation

So when I am trying to install cryptography via

```
python -m pip install cryptography
```

I get two error messages coming back:

> 1. Failed building wheel for cryptography
> 2. command "/usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/private/var/folders/qf/57zhxjfn4hl95y8xg7l12xpm0000gn/T/pip-build-DBR7_Y/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/qf/57zhxjfn4hl95y8xg7l12xpm0000gn/T/pip-msQ3gT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/qf/57zhxjfn4hl95y8xg7l12xpm0000gn/T/pip-build-DBR7_Y/cryptography

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Execute `/usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='/private/var/folders/qf/57zhxjfn4hl95y8xg7l12xpm0000gn/T/pip-build-DBR7_Y/cryptography/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/qf/57zhxjfn4hl95y8xg7l12xpm0000gn/T/pip-msQ3gT-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile` (the command that failed) and show the output.

Answer (score 0):

Like in your other post [Trouble with running pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926435/trouble-with-running-pip-install)

run your same command with `sudo`

Answer (score 0):

may be its dependecies hang on your netword, you could install them first
in my case, it depend on idna, enum34, ipaddress, pycparser, so

```
 pip install idna enum34 ipaddress pycparser
```

and then install cryptography

```
`pip install cryptography`
```

how to know cryptography's dependecies?
cryptography's dependecies depend on system environment, when it hang on, you can find the log like this, first line is its dependecies.

```
Installing collected packages: cryptography, idna, enum34, ipaddress, pycparser
Running setup.py install for cryptography
warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'tests'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'yacctab.*' found under directory 'examples'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'lextab.*' found under directory 'examples'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was running an old version of pip, getting this error message:

```
You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.1 is available.
```

You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

I simply updated to the newest version, I had no trouble installing:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```